# Changing the default main file "index.js" to some other file in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been thinking about the topic of changing the main file in react but I couldn't get through. Please, Can anyone explain whether can we change, if not then why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to create-react-app. In which case the answer is no: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure.

You can always [eject](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) a create-react-app, but IMO it is not really worth it unless you need some really specific configuration.

Keep in mind that you don't have to use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) to use [react proper](https://reactjs.org/). If you use react by itself, you can apply any organization you wish.

Comment: hi @David Varela, In Node.JS we can configure our main file, where as in react the only main file "index.js" (entry point) right. Any way thanks for taking your precious time and answering.. : ) : )

Answer (score 1):

If it is app.js you can change any file to render a root id div in react app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change app.js you can change the following line in **index.js** file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App /> // Change To Your Default File
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Don't forget to import the file