# How to rename 'index.js' file in React File structure to something else?

Tags: reactjs

In the React file structure under `components` there is `index.js` file that runs the main character when running the project. Is there anyway to rename this file to any name I want? I am using `PM2` server manager and there is no way for me to keep track which server is which when running multiple `index.js` files. So the only option I got is to rename this `index.js` to something specific to each project.

I have tried changing the `package.json` file's `start` script as below but nothing worked out only gave errors.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "test.js react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Appreciate all your help!

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823500/changing-the-default-main-file-index-js-to-some-other-file-in-react) Stack Overflow post? Maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name of the file used by create-react-path.

You'll have to either eject to use custom webpack config by running

```
npm run eject
```

But it's a one-way operation (see [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/cra-template/template/README.md))

Or you can use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) instead of create-react-app to bundle your project.

Vite is more configurable than create-react-app, you define in the index.html the name of your js file. So you can put any name you want.
Maybe even this example could help you:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#example-projects